# Unable to fetch data from mongodb collection using monggose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here is my code.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/myDB');
var Docsession = mongoose.model('docsession', new Schema({ cookieval: String, secref: String, id: Number}));
Docsession.find({'cookieval' : 'umesh'},function(err,arr) {
console.log(arr);
console.log('length='+arr.length);
});
```

my result is returning no value. Don't know if I'm using find in right way.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you're not populating the database

```
  var umesh = new Docsession({ cookieval: 'umesh', secref: 'abcd', id: 100 });
  umesh.save(function (err) {
     if (err)
        console.log('Error');
  })
  Docsession.find({'cookieval' : 'umesh'} ,function(err,arr) {
  console.log(arr);
  console.log('length='+arr.length);
  })
```

will return

```
  [ { cookieval: 'umesh',
     secref: 'abcd',
     id: 100,
     _id: 4fc5924c5bfd08db61000001 } ]
  length=1
```